# Change Button color and text onPress

Tags: react-native

I implementing recording in my react native app. I want a button that changes its color and text on press and change back on press again.

moreover, a timer that shows recording duration while recording.

Comment: Can you please share what you have managed to do so far?

Comment: Currently I have two buttons on my app. one for record and another one is for stop recording. I want to use just one  instead of two separate buttons.

Comment: Please share the code in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

For the button, I would try something similar to this (assuming you are using functional components):

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native'
function App(){
const {buttonPress, setButtonPress} = useState(false)
const togglePress = () => {
      setButtonPress(!buttonPress)
}

<TouchableOpacity 

onPress={togglePress)
style={{backgroundColor: buttonPress ? "white" : "red"}}
>
<Text>Hello world!</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Not sure about the second part of your question though.